# findout if numeric editText is filled out or not

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I have a *EditText* named countOfProduct(Number editText type, when user want to insert into this, just numbers of keyborad display) and an if in which i want to see that end user insert a number or not.
I googled and find many solutions, but none of them worked for me.

Here is my if:

```
 if(!countOfProduct.getText().toString().equals("") ||
   !countOfProduct.getText().toString().matches("")||
   !countOfProduct.getText().toString().matches(null) ||
   !countOfProduct.getText().toString().equals(null) ||
   !countOfProduct.getText().toString().isEmpty() ||
   !countOfProduct.getText().equals(null) ||
   (countOfProduct.getText().length() ==0) ||
   (countOfProduct.getText().toString().length() ==0))
```

what should i do?

Comment: I think you should use `TextWatcher` for `EditText`..!!

Comment: Do you want to check if the editText is empty or check what the user is typing while he/she is typing?

Comment: @MirianaItani i want to check if it is empty or not.
Doesnt matter what he/she insert.

Comment: What I usually do is the following: string!= null && !string.trim().isEmpty(); I get the string from the edittext this way: string= textfilde.getText().toString. Let me know if that worked out for u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
 String myString = countOfProduct.getText().toString();
 if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myString)) {
    if (tryParseInt(myString))
        Log.d("IS A NUMBER", "");

 }


 boolean tryParseInt(String value) {  
 try {  
     Integer.parseInt(value);  
     return true;  
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
     return false;  
  }  
 }
```

Comment: i just used : 
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(countOfProduct.getText())

and it works.Thx alot.

Comment: Your code as it is might not compile, because `EditText.getText()` returns an `Editable` object, not a string: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()

Comment: @McAdam331 yes, sorry, I made a mistake.
Now it should works.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `String.isEmpty()` to check:

```
if(myEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
   // Bad input
}
```

It has always worked fine for me.

**EDIT**

Note, `TextUtils.isEmpty()` can take an `Editable` object (since this class implements `CharSequence`), so if you prefer you can use that method to avoid calling `.toString()`:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditText.getText())) {
   // Bad input
}
```

Comment: You are right, i should use TextUtils class.
But isEmpty for calling .toString doesnt worked for me.

Comment: Here(In this cope that i check the editText) i call an SP and the value passed to that SP.
If the value contains null the program unfortunately stopped !
but as i did the check using TextUtil class, it was ok and get an Toas.makeText().show that he/she should insert some number.

Comment: Here is what i used

!TextUtils.isEmpty(countOfProduct.getText())

and again thx ,

Comment: @The.Only.One I'm glad you've got it working, I'm just baffled why my first solution doesn't. Either way, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Always remember: `EditText.getText()` will never return `null`.

This alone is enough if you don't care about spaces:

```
if(countOfProduct.getText().length() != 0){
     // This means that the EditText is not empty
}
```

If you do care about spaces, then use this:

```
if(countOfProduct.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){
     // This means that the EditText is not empty.
}
```

Comment: does not work .
as you see its a number type of editText.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of `EditText` it is. As long as it's an `EditText` the above should work. If i am not wrong, you just want to check if the `EditText` is empty or not, right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the user insert only number first of all you have to declare it into xml layout with *android:inputType* attribute:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/count_of_product"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:inputType="number" >
```

then add a **TextWatcher** to your EditText:

```
countOfProduct.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //insert your checks here
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            };
        });
```

check [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to know how to use *TextWatcher*